# Ext JS ComboBox Dynamic Behaviour

Tags: combobox, extjs, dynamic-data, datastore

I am trying to load/show completely different set of values in a combobox(this one resides as a editor within an EditorGridPanel) based on the valueField of another combobox(this one resides outside the grid in top bar). I have already seen a tutorial(http://www.extjs.com/learn/Tutorial%3ALinked%5FCombos%5FTutorial%5Ffor%5FExt%5F2) wherein ALL the values for the secondary object are stored locally and then filtered however, I have already created a link which will supply me with json data based on the valuefield, so I would like to use this url to keep the code efficient.

I have also tried to refresh the datastore but its simply not being reflected on the combobox.

Please advise

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution, loading values from a url is straightforward.. if you want to manipulate the query(like I wanted), you would have to strip url off the dynamic parameters and assign them to baseParams of the store and then call store.load()

It worked for me!!